# How to open SerialPort only when data received, not all the time, in C#?

Tags: c#, arduino

I have written the function `DataReceivedHandler`, and it works perfectly, but the port should be kept open to read coming data. On my project, the port should be keept available so other pages can use it if there isn't any data coming from Arduino. How can I open it only when the data received?

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler( object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

    string indata = "";
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    // Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    if (indata == "kitchen_light_on\r\n")
        f1.update_flag("kitchen_light", 1);
    else
        if(indata == "kitchen_light_off\r\n")
            f1.update_flag("kitchen_light", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need one `SerialPort` object which stays open and is shared by all the various pages.

Note that the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class is designed badly, and you've fallen into one of its traps.  You can never compare the result of `ReadExisting()` to anything, because you might get part of your data now and part later.  You first have to concatenate together an entire message and then you can process it.  Or you might get multiple messages at once, in which case you'll need to split them apart before processing.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with Ben. If your goal is to make sure to get the complete message and nothing dirty attached to it for your Windows program to understand what to do, I would recommend to use header and tail identifiers, something like `>hereYourMessage<` and/or to make your messages from the Arduino much shorter.

You can then recognize a complete message taking the characters/number or whatsoever between the >< and strip them out to pass the message to get fired.